# Can someone toll me if it's possible to use request.POST in manager

Tags: python, django

whatever i try, i'm getting the error: **'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'POST'**

```
class ChargeManager(models.Manager):

    def charge_credit_card(self, amount, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Charge a credit card
        """
        creditCard.cardNumber = self.request.POST.get('card_number')
        creditCard.expirationDate = self.request.POST.get('expir_date')
```

Comment: removing `self` should solve the issue

Comment: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'POST'  without self

Answer (score 0):

we can't pass request.Post in manager, it's primary role is to filter the result.

so i succeed passing card_number in the parameter and than request.Post in the view

```
creditCard.cardNumber = self.model(card_number=card_number)
```